# Why is my this.props.navigation.setParams not working?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm setting my integer array on selectedStyleIds. Why is my this.props.navigaion.setParams not working?

```
  _setSelectedStyleIds = (selectedStyleIds) => {
    const action = NavigationActions.setParams({ 
        params: {selectedStyleIds},
        key: 'id-1509842157447-6' <- got this from console
    });
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(action);
    this.props.navigation.setParams({styleIds:selectedStyleIds});
    this.setState({selectedStyleIds});
  }

onCheck = ({selectedStyleIds}) => {
    console.log('onCheck');
    console.log(selectedStyleIds); <- [1,2,3,4,5]
    this.props._setSelectedStyleIds(selectedStyleIds);
    this.setState({selectedStyleIds}); <- working
}



_handleTagStylePress = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('TagStyle', {onCheck: this.onCheck, selectedStyleIds: this.state.selectedStyleIds});
}
```

on onNavigatioOptions (just for debugging)

```
onPress={() => {
          let {image, text, ..., selectedSeasonIds,
            gender, selectedSizeIds, selectedColorIds, selectedStyleIds,
            brand, ..., base64 } = navigation.state.params;
          console.log('onsave')
          console.log(navigation.state.params.selectedStyleIds) <<-- []
```

I've been checking these lines more than 50 times but apparently `this.props.navigation.setParams({selectedStyleIds});` is not working.

All other things have no problem on setting state and params but ONLY the selectedStyleIds can't be set to `navigation.state.params`.

Comment: I'm debugging it letter by letter now.

Comment: Could you please try ```const action = NavigationActions.setParams({ params: {}, key: '..' });``` and after that ```navigation.dispatch(action);``` ?

Comment: const action = NavigationActions.setParams({ params: {selectedStyleIds}, key: '..' });
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(action);
    this.props.navigation.setParams({selectedStyleIds});

Comment: Not working :( Am I doing right here?

Comment: key should have the route key such as Home, Profile etc, not  ```..```

Comment: Should I put `const action = NavigationActions.setParams({ params: {}, key: '..' }); and after that navigation.dispatch(action);`???? in navigationOptions? or in _setSelectedSizeIds?

Comment: Please define "not working".

Comment: Thanks for asking. not working = setParams is not performed.

Comment: @JohnBaek In ```_setSelectedSizeIds```

Comment: @htkibar I just edited the question with your suggestion. :) it's not working but do you see any problem on that? Thanks

Comment: @JohnBaek exactly the same problem for me

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had a similar problem, regarding setting the title of the navigation bar from within the component itself.

The following worked for me.

1) I defined the `navigationOptions` method (callback method of react navigation to set navigation properties)

When this method runs, you are very likely not to have access to the properties that are needed to set the navigator state, so simply return the current parameters, this is what I did:

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { params } = navigation.state;
    return params;
};
```

2) I implemented the title construction in componentDidMount, setting the state:

```
componentDidMount(){
    t = "The window title";
    this.props.navigation.setParams({title: t });
}
```

I think the same could be done in any user interface event, like the `onPress`, and can be applied to any property.

**Important note:** What made the difference to me between *not working* and *working* was the definition of the `navigationOptions` method, even if it is a "do-nothing" method (returns what it gets, unchanged)

Comment: I'm having the problem of not being able to set the header with different screens. I'm also trying for about a week with various ways. Seems that is doesn't render the title properly when setParams is called. Tried this but it also doesn't work.

Comment: So, you're defining the `navigationOptions` method in the component? Or in the navigator definition somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Now in 2020 it seems like the official documentation of react native suggests that you use route.param to get the params you want.

```
        const { itemId } = route.params;
```

This is from the official documentation:

Pass params to a route by putting them in an object as a second parameter to the navigation.navigate function: navigation.navigate('RouteName', { /* params go here */ })

Read the params in your screen component: route.params.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/

Answer (score 0):

**you could do as follows**

```
const handleCancelTransfer = useCallback(() => {
  navigation.dispatch((state) => {
    const routes = state.routes.filter((routeInStack) => routeInStack.name !== "TransferConfirmation");
    routes[routes.length - 1] = {
      ...routes[routes.length - 1],
      params: { keepFormData: true }
    }
    return CommonActions.reset({
      ...state,
      routes,
      index: routes.length - 1,
    })
  });
}, [navigation]);
```