# Setting redux state with navigation parameter

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

Outside of my component, I have redux snippets where I am trying to pass some parameters through a navigation and set it as the initialState. However, it returns the error 'cannot read property of 'navigation'':

```
const initialState = this.props.navigation.setParam('initialState, {});

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'UPDATE_BASE_PREMIUM':
            return { ...state, basePremium: action.payload / 100 }
        case 'UPDATE_TOTAL_PREMIUM':
            return { ...state, totalPremium: action.payload / 100 }
        case 'CHANGE_MODE_OF_PAYMENT':
            return { ...state, modeOfPayment: action.payload }
        case 'CHANGE_FIRST_NAME':
            return { ...state, firstName: action.payload }
        case 'CHANGE_LAST_NAME':
            return { ...state, lastName: action.payload }
        case 'CHANGE_DOB':
```

If I run 'this.props.navigation.setParam('initialState, {});' within the component itself however, then it runs perfectly, but in this case, initialState is still not changed:

```
export default class SavedIllustrations extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        }
    }

    static navigationOptions = {
        header: null
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        initialState = this.props.navigation.getParam('initialState', {});
        console.log(initialState);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.container}>
                    <HeaderLogo />
                    <NewSaveIllustration navigation={this.props.navigation} />
                    <ReviewSavePrint />
                    <Calculator />
                    <InsuredInformation />
                    <BasePlan />
                    <TermRiders />
                    <OptionalBenefitRiders />
                </ScrollView>
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}
```

What would be the best method to import an initialState through a navigation parameter?

Comment: did you check this out :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47093555/why-is-my-this-props-navigation-setparams-not-working